# Calling Array Key on Assigned Function Returned Array?

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.6

From PHP **5.4**, I can call an **element** of a **function returned array**, like so: `func()['el']`.

I'm running PHP **5.6** and test the following (simplified) code:

## Works

```
$decoded = json_decode($content, true)['foo'];
```

## Doesn't Work

```
($decoded = json_decode($content, true))['foo']; // syntax error ['
```

I don't understand why I cannot assign `json_decode($content, true)` to `$decoded` and call the element `foo` immediately. This works fine in php **7**

## Why this is Interesting?

My **PhpStorm 2017.2.1**, with applied **php 5.6** **DOESN'T** detect this code as **available in PHP 7 only!**

Comment: cannot reproduce : https://3v4l.org/b8Q0R. You might not be running the php version you think you are.

Comment: I think your json $content has some issue, can you share $conent

Comment: `($decoded = json_decode($content, true))['foo'];` syntax is not correct for 5.6. have a look at https://3v4l.org/v3Tqt

Comment: @ChetanAmeta I know, but that's the last part of my question

Comment: I added a section to my question about PhpStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the many features that PHP 7 introduced was an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/abstract_syntax_tree). This directly led to more complex expressions being possible, such as the one in your question.

Simply, the change is that a function return wrapped in brackets previously did not behave the same as one that is not:

```
<?php
function foo() { return ['a' => 'b']; }

echo foo()['a']; // Works in PHP 5.4+
echo (foo())['a']; // Works in PHP 7+
```

Functional array dereferencing, as you mention, was added in 5.4, but only as a special case in the parser. In PHP 7+, you can dereference any expression that yields an array.